# Permissions denied and cannot change permissions for files on external drive

Tags: 14.04, permissions

I upgraded to 14.04. I was very content with 12.04, never had a problem.

Once I upgraded, at first I wasn't able to access my network on my Windows laptops. I finally created a new samba user, while before I could just use my system login. I can access my network now, but certain files deny me permission. I gave samba users full access; I have tried to change permissions in nautilus, but they will not change. I have `chmod ug+rxw file name`. This is my external drive, but I have even copied over to another directory on my internal drive just to see, and I still get permission denied from my laptops.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check and edit your /etc/samba/smb.conf

I think you'll find useful reading [THIS](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1962617.html)

pay particular attention to the explanations about:
security = user
map to guest = Bad User

and

force user = [username]
force group = [group]